# How to pass all props in one variable in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to assign all props in one object and pass all of them in one variable.

Here is my code:

```
function Slider(props){
    return (
    
        <div className="hero-wrap js-fullheight" style={{height: "1041px"}}>
            <div className="container-fluid px-0">
                <div className="row d-md-flex">
                    <img className="one-third " src={undraw}></img>
                    <div className="one-forth>
                        <div className="text mt-5">
                            <span className="subheading">{props.subheading}</span>
                            <h1 className="mb-3">{props.title}</h1>
                            <p>{props.text}</p>
                            <p><a  href="#" className="btn btn-primary">{props.btnCourses}</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

const IndexPage = () => {

    let sliderProps = {
        subheading: 'Hi',
        title: 'Hi',
        text: 'Ipsum ut nostrud excepteur qui qui quis exercitation minim Lorem',
        btnCourses: 'Hi'
    };

    return (
        <Slider props={sliderProps} />
    );
}
```

At here I don't want to write them in `<Slider />` and want to assign them out of the return and assign them like `props={sliderProps}` How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following.

```
const IndexPage = () => {

    let sliderProps = {
        subheading: 'Hi',
        title: 'Hi',
        text: 'Ipsum ut nostrud excepteur qui qui quis exercitation minim Lorem',
        btnCourses: 'Hi'
    };

    return (
        <Slider {...sliderProps} />
    );
}
```

to prevent using props every where on your component, you can also destructor it.

```
const Slider = props => {
    const { title, undraw, text, btnCourses } = props;
    return (
    
        <div className="hero-wrap js-fullheight" style={{height: "1041px"}}>
            <div className="container-fluid px-0">
                <div className="row d-md-flex">
                    <img className="one-third " src={undraw}></img>
                    <div className="one-forth>
                        <div className="text mt-5">
                            <span className="subheading">{subheading}</span>
                            <h1 className="mb-3">{title}</h1>
                            <p>{text}</p>
                            <p><a  href="#" className="btn btn-primary">{btnCourses}</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```